# Countdown timer doesn't stop [Android]

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

this is my first time here and i need ur help.
My activity starts calling this method, and theres a button that is supposed to restart the timer. The button contains the same method, but it doesn't restart. The method code has the timer.cancel in the end but it doesn't do the job, the timer keeps running and I cant get it. I really need a hand.

```
public final void starTimer() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String num = extras.getString("seg");
        timerr = new CountDownTimer((Integer.parseInt(num)) * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long millis = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                if (millis<10){
                    txtTempo.setText("0"+ (millisUntilFinished / 1000)) ;
                } else {
                    txtTempo.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                }            
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                txtTempo.setText("00");
               }
             });

           }
         };
        timerr.cancel();
        timerr.start();
    }
```

Comment: Stop your timer like yourCountDownTimer.cancel();

Comment: call  timerr.start(); first then call timerr.cancel();

Comment: If you want to cancel timer then check if(timerr!=null) timerr.cancel(); and then create timer instance currently you are creating new instance and call cancel() due to new instance old reference is break and it is not accessible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    public final void starTimer() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String num = extras.getString("seg");
        if(timerr!=null){
          timerr.cancel();
          timerr=null;
        }
        timerr = new CountDownTimer((Integer.parseInt(num)) * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long millis = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
                if (millis<10){
                    txtTempo.setText("0"+ (millisUntilFinished / 1000)) ;
                } else {
                    txtTempo.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                }            
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                txtTempo.setText("00");
               }
             });

           }
         };

        timerr.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call  timerr.cancel() onDestroy()/onDestroyView() in the Activity/Fragment.

or call separate method

```
timerr = new CountDownTimer((Integer.parseInt(num)) * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished / 1000;
        if (millis<10){
            txtTempo.setText("0"+ (millisUntilFinished / 1000)) ;
        } else {
            txtTempo.setText("" + (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        }            
    }
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        txtTempo.setText("00");
       }
     });

   }
 };

 timerr.start();
 }
```

Use method whenever you want cancel the timer

cancelTimer();

```
  void cancelTimer() {
   if(timerr!=null)
    timerr.cancel();
  }
```